# Memory leak on uiwebview alloc

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiview, uiwebview

In my app I have a uiwebview which I used to display image file. Now the problem is I am getting a leak in this view. I have written the following code:

```
UIWebView *the_pWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]]; // the leak is on this line. 
the_pWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
the_pWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
the_pWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
the_pWebView.delegate = self;

self.m_pWebView = the_pWebView;
[self.view addSubview: self.m_pWebView];
[the_pWebView release];
```

In the first line of the code, where I am allocing the uiwebview, why would this be leaking even if I have released it?

Answer (score 2):

If the `m_pWebView` property is `retain` or `copy` then you need to make sure you release it in your `dealloc` method on that class. I suspect you're not releasing it there.

Comment: for m_pWebView, i have defined property(nonatomic, retain) and have also released it in the dealloc method. even then this leak is being shown.

Answer (score 0):

You should also release self.m_pWebView after adding it to self.view

Comment: i have released it in the dealloc method. i cannot release it as soon as i add it to self.view. i use it other places too.

Comment: The retain count after adding it to self.view is 2, you should then release it so as the dealloc function can destroy it completely!

Comment: Update: if you add the self.m_pWebView to self.view, you are not responsible anymore of its deallocation(if you release it after the adding operation). self.view will destroy its subviews on dealloc.

Answer (score 0):

in ViewDidLoad

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(abc) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

then make a function name is abc

```
   -(void) abc
    {

 UIWebView *the_pWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]]; 

 the_pWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

the_pWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

the_pWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

 the_pWebView.delegate = self;

 self.m_pWebView = the_pWebView;


  [self.view addSubview: self.m_pWebView];

  [the_pWebView release];

iWebView=nil;

 }
```